# I've been getting this error every time click on the Google sign in button "[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]:

Tags: flutter

```
vTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:50294/dart_sdk.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
VM989 client:201 [GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: Instantiated.
dart_sdk.js:5397 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Assertion failed: file:///C:/Users/computer%20planet/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_sign_in_web-0.12.0/lib/google_sign_in_web.dart:147:9
appClientId != null
"ClientID not set. Either set it on a <meta name=\"google-signin-client_id\" content=\"CLIENT_ID\" /> tag, or pass clientId when initializing GoogleSignIn"
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (dart_sdk.js:5397:11)
    at Object.assertFailed (dart_sdk.js:5315:15)
    at google_sign_in_web.GoogleSignInPlugin.new.initWithParams (google_sign_in_web.dart.lib.js:204:42)
```

Issues with Flutter web Google sign in.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the client id in index file. You have to go to your `web/index.html` file and add your google sign in meta tag:

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```